# Finding the IP address of the docker container

Tags: python, docker, dockerfile, fastapi, docker-network

I have set up a fast-api docker container. I need to communicate with fast-api present in my docker container running locally through http requests, however I am not able to determine the IP address in which my fast-api docker container is running. My dockerfile is:

```
FROM jhonatans01/python-dlib-opencv
COPY . .
RUN pip3 install -r requirements.txt
CMD ["uvicorn", "main:app", "--reload"]
```

When I run fast-api locally by,

```
uvicorn main:app --reload
```

the terminal tells me where the instance is running. However docker does not provide any output. I have looked at http://192.168.99.100 and http://127.0.0.1 with no success.

Comment: try ```docker ps -a```, it will list the docker port and if docker is running locally it would be ```localhost``` or ```127.0.0.1```

Comment: That requires a port to be mapped (`-p` argument).

Answer (score 3):

Here is what worked for me to find IP address of the container:

**docker inspect -f '{{range .NetworkSettings.Networks}}{{.IPAddress}}{{end}}' your_container_id**

Answer (score 3):

```
docker exec <container_id> sh -c "hostname --ip-address"
```

Answer (score -1):

While running the application with `docker run`, you can pass an option called `--network host`. This will run your application on 127.0.0.1

*You will not need the container IP to access your application*

But, if you want to know the container IP in any case
you can do

```
docker ps 
// to list all the docker containers

docker inspect <container_id> 
// you will get container_id from the output of 1st command
```

This will give you a json including all information (and of course the IP)

---

Another solution :

As Kiaus's comment suggests ..

You can do port binding, means you have to pass option `-p <port1>:<port2>` in the `docker run` command

say, your python app is running on `8000`
you can pass `-p 7000:8000` and now your app will open on `localhost:7000`

Comment: `--network host` generally disables Docker's networking layer; you should almost never need it, and it's not an appropriate way to routinely connect to a container.  The container-private IP addresses are also unusable except in one very specific Docker host OS setup and it's never necessary to look them up.